# What electrical panel is this?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have an awkward question about my house. Since I am remote now, I cannot confirm the detail of the electrical panel. But I took 2 pictures before. This IS what INSIDE the panel:

[image]

**Question 1:** Does this look like a 200 AMP panel?

Sorry I don't have more details.

I believe I replaced the panel years back as it was old.

**Question 2:** Just to confirm, *below* is NOT the same one *above* right?

[image]

Comment: Your 1st pic looks exactly like the Square-D HOM1224L125PC panel I bought a few weeks ago. 125A, 12-space / 24-circuit, plug-on neutral bars on each side. Square-D doesn't appear to make a 200A version in the 12/24 size.

Comment: Q2 ... definitely not the same panel ...  just look at the wall

Comment: Looks like 2 sub panels to me, definitely not your main panel.

Comment: @brhans a panel that looks the same but is +20 years older may not have had the ability to use double stuff or tandem breakers this is a difference and there doesn’t appear to be the rejection feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was recently browsing Square D's HOMeline catalog, and I can tell you their 12-*space* panels are 125A busing.    That's what you have in the first photo.

As for the ampacity of the 6-space panel in the second photo, *you can read that yourself right on the label*.

18 spaces in total is not nearly enough for a modern house. Especially if you have 200A service, you surely have a third panel somewhere else.  Given the number of breakers in these panels and their lack of a main breaker, I gather these are sub panels to another main panel elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> Just to confirm, below is NOT the same one above right?

Can't be the same. The top picture has two rows (columns) of breakers and the bottom picture has one row of breakers. As already noted, the top one can't be terribly big based on the size of the lugs, but generally speaking except for Meter Mains, small panels tend to be lower capacity. The top appears to be a 12 space panel - my guess would be 100 Amp maximum, and may be even less.

Answer (score 0):

That’s a square D main lug panel with a 100 amp rating on the bottom Or the panel with a row of breakers.

Without the label we can not tell how large the one with 2 vertical rows of breakers
Is but the lugs look quite small  I doubt it would be a 200 but it is possible the 200 usually had closer to 20 slots. But not always.

All the panels of that size I could find maxed out at 125 amp
Not unusual because it is hard to find breakers any larger to feed a Main Lug Only sub.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes as the answer is similar to both the others. And we don’t know without the label